# Invalid Syntax/unexpected indent error in simple function (Python 3.6)

Tags: python-3.x

Python has repeatedly been giving me these invalid syntax errors, followed by unexpected indent errors, when I believe my code is correct. I have checked many times for things like tabs vs. spaces so I'm lead to believe its something I don't know about yet that could be going wrong, since I'm also fairly new to python.

Heres my code

```
def removeDups(L1,L2):
    for i in L2[:]:
        if i in L1:
            L2.remove(i)
```

I'm sure its a simple fix but I've been trying to figure it out for a while to no avail so if anyone can help thank you.

Also here are the errors I get

```
File "<stdin>", line 5
def removeDups(L1,L2):
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>             L2.remove(i)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    for i in L2:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> def removeDups(L1,L2):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if i in L1:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>     for i in L2:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    L2.remove(i)
    ^
```

Comment: Why not just do `s = set(L1); L2 = [x for x in L2 if x not in s]`?

Comment: Well i'm doing it multiple ways but they all pretty much get the same errors. I did one using set differencing and I got the same errors so im really perplexed by this issue. I'll try and make one with your code though also.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're typing this into the REPL instead of using a script?

Comment: What is the code above `def removeDups(L1,L2):`? That seems to be causing the error

Comment: There is no code above the function currently. Also I'm typing this in Spyder because thats what my teacher has us use, I mean we can switch but I just kinda started on this and havent switched yet.

Comment: @xek Okay, it seems like there's issues when copying your code into an interpreter. Just run it as a script: `python script.py`.

Comment: Hmmm. Not that thats too inconvienent, but is there a way to fix it so it works in my interpreter? I'll try running it as a script in the meantime